# join three table which status finish or null

Tags: sql

I have three table

```
tbl_status                            tbl_simpan             tbl_mitra
==================================   ====================   =====================
id_status|id_projek|status_projek|   |id_mitra|id_projek|   |id_mitra|nama_mitra|
==================================   ====================   =====================
1        |31301    |Finish       |   |13001   |31301    |   |13001   |Arturia   |
2        |31302    |Finish       |   |13002   |31302    |   |13002   |Herona    |
3        |31303    |Ongoing      |   |13001   |31303    |   |13003   |Telkom    |
```

IF I join these three table:

```
==================================
|id_mitra|id_projek|status_projek|
=================================|
|13001   |31301    |Finish       |
|13002   |31302    |Finish       |
|13001   |31303    |Ongoing      |
|13003   |NULL     |NULL         |
```

I want to show nama_mitra which status 'Finish' and NULL, but if id_mitra is ongoing, it didn't show. See **id_mitra 13001** is already **finish** but it **Ongoing** again with different projek. So, I want to have this:

Result

```
============
|nama_mitra|
============
|Herona    |
|Telkom    |
============
```

what I've tried:

```
SELECT nama_mitra as 'Nama Mitra' from tbl_mitra m 
full outer join tbl_simpan s on m.id_mitra=s.id_mitra 
full outer join tbl_status st on s.id_projek=st.id_projek 
where status_projek is null or status_projek like 'Finish'
```

I also tried with left outer join but I got same result.

Can anybody help me to get this result?

Comment: can you show your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated (new):

```
SELECT m.Nama_Mitra
FROM tbl_mitra m
full outer join  
(select id_mitra, max(id_projek) as id_projek 
 from tbl_simpan
 group by id_mitra) s on m.id_mitra = s.id_mitra
full outer join tbl_status st on s.id_projek = st.id_projek
WHERE st.status_projek ='Finish' OR s.id_projek IS NULL
```

the table `s` gets the last `id_projek` for `id_mita` (to capture the ongoing status)

Comment: Um..still no, See id_mitra 13001 is already finish but it Ongoing again, I think that's my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.nama_mitra FROM tbl_mitra m 
INNER JOIN tbl_simpan s ON s.id_mitra = m.id_mitra 
INNER JOIN tbl_status st ON st.id_projek = s.id_projek 
WHERE st.status_projek = 'Finish'
```

Comment: but this only show the finish one, I also want to show the one that don't exist on tbl_status